# How to create a timetable in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uikit, timetable

is there any framework for iOS that allows to create a time table like this app:

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id335495816?mt=8

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I've seen (unless you code a custom view like they did) is MAWeek and Day View.

http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/maweekview

http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/madayview

On the day view, it looks like a UITableView with custom UITableViewCells (the one with the remaining time).  To do that, create custom UITableViewCells:

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/2/28/speeding-up-table-view-cell-loading-with-uinib.html

Comment: Thanks! thats actually what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Found an amazing weekly view timetable system using the weekly tapku API [TapKu weekly view](https://github.com/muhku/calendar-ui)